# Using tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient.fetch() to make a GET request along with parameters

Tags: asynchronous, get, tornado

As mentioned in the title, i want to make a asynchronous GET request using the fetch() method of AsyncHTTPclient.

But, I can't figure out where to give the query parameters.

So, say I want to make the request

`http://xyz.com?a=1&b=2`

where do I give the `a` and `b`? Is the only way to do this is by appending the parameters to the URL. Specifically, is there a way to pass a Dict which then gets appended to the URL by the Tornado framework.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
from tornado.httputil import url_concat
params = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
url = url_concat("http://example.com/", params)

http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
http_client.fetch(url, request_callback_handler)
```

Comment: @Karthik: I've found that tornado has it's own function for that, update the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use tornado HTTPRequest also to make request object and then you can use the httpclient with request object as parameter in the fetch.

[Link for tornado HTTPRequest doc](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#response-objects)

Code sample for HTTPRequest

```
import tornado.httpclient
import urllib

url = 'http://example.com/'
body = urllib.urlencode({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
req = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(url, 'GET', body=body)

# I have used synchronous one (you can use async one with callback)
client = tornado.httpclient.HTTPClient()

res = client.fetch(req)
```

Comment: I think the `body` keyword can not be used with `GET` method, just try in tornado(4.1).

Comment: In python3 urlencode has moved to `urllib.parse`.  E.g try: `urllib.parse.urlencode({'a':123})`

Answer (score 3):

You can simply include them in the URL:

```
def handle_request(response):
    if response.error:
        print "Error:", response.error
    else:
        print response.body

http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
http_client.fetch("http://www.google.com/?q=tornado", handle_request)
```

Reffering through [documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest) then `tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest` object doesn't provide any interfaces to supply parameterized variable set for building a query string that can be appended to URL.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. But most frameworks provide a way to pass dictionaries that are then appended to the URL. Just wanted to know if Tornado had such facility